# Python Unit testing script that calls some functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I ended up with testing an "automation" script in python, basically just a script calling bunch of functions.

I have 3 classes: class_A, class_B, class_C, with each class having a "run" function

Script.py is calling class_A.run(), class_B.run, class_C.run()

My question would be if is there is a way of unit testing Script.py to just assert if the 3 run functions we're called, without actually running (going trough their code) them.

I tried patching the class and i can get the correct assert, but the run functions are still "running" their code.

Is it possible to somehow Mock the class_A.run() and assert if was called?

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Mock patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).
The MockClass will replace your module.class_A and the run-method:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('module.class_A', 'run')
def test(MockClass):
    Script.py  # your testfunction 
    assert MockClass.run.called  # check if module.Class_A.run() was called
```

Comment: Mention: path for class A in my case was "python_framework.utils.Class_A" and path for "Script.py" is "python_framework.Script". Once i patched the function using "pyton_framework.Script.Class_A.run" everything worked. *Before i was patching "python_framework.utils.Class_A.run"